# Enable XML-RPC on Xampp

Tags: php, xampp, odoo, xml-rpc, ripcord

I'm working on a project and I need to connect to Odoo via XML-RPC. The documentation suggests using Ripcord library, and for this I need to enable XML-RPC on my enviroment, but I've got no clue how to do this. I've been googleing for the last couple of days but couldnt find answers on a similar setting that I could understand.

Im working on XAMPP for Mac, and the PHP version is 8.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to install xmlrpc extension with following commands:

```
git clone https://git.php.net/repository/pecl/networking/xmlrpc.git
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2/
cd xmlrpc && phpize && ./configure --with-expat && make && make install
echo "extension=xmlrpc.so" > /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/xmlrpc.ini
```

That's how I installed it on my Ubuntu.

Also you can check [this](https://affinitybridge.com/blog/adding-php-extensions-system-php-under-os-x-1015-catalina) if you don't know how to compile extensions on OS X

Comment: I think it would be worth checking if it isn't already included/enabled before compiling...

Comment: `XML-RPC support in PHP is not enabled by default` source https://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlrpc.installation.php also if php watch is reliable enough - https://php.watch/versions/8.0/xmlrpc

Comment: Great point, thanks for clarifying that and have an upvote!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried directly by opening the terminal from Xampp but had problems with the expat configuration.

Just to be sure, in which route should I be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try download xmlrpc extension in pecl website and install the compatible dll into your xampp.

1. Go to https://pecl.php.net/package/xmlrpc and download the dll
2. Copy the .dll file to your **xampp/php/ext** folder
3. Add this text to your **php.ini**

> extension=php_xmlrpc.dll

4. Restart apache service
5. Done